# Monogame: Song being cut off

Tags: c#, audio, monogame

For some reason, when I play a Song, it cuts off the last second or so of the song, even when repeating.

Is this a Monogame bug, or am I doing something wrong?
There's nothing out of the ordinary in my code, as far as I can tell:

```
public static void Load(JoyGame game)
{
        s_Music = new Dictionary<string, Song>();

        MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += PlayLoop;

        string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Content/Music";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            string name = FileNameExtractor.ExtractName(files[i], 3);
            s_Music.Add(name, game.Content.Load<Song>("Music/" + name + ".ogg"));
        }
}

public static void Play(string song)
{
        MediaPlayer.Stop();
        if(s_Music.ContainsKey(song + "Loop"))
        {
            s_CurrentSong = song + "Loop";
            MediaPlayer.Play(s_Music[s_CurrentSong]);
            MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
        }
}
```